# Can we use wildcard within pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have below code thats working but it throws some `UserWarning` while printing the data..

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)

data = pd.read_csv('/home/karn/plura/Test/Python_Pnada/Cyber_July.csv', usecols=['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address', 'Failure reason'])
hostData = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CS-Unix-")][data['Safe'].str.startswith("CS-NOI-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT")] [['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address','Failure reason']]
hostData.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(hostData)
```

Below is the UserWarning ..

```
./CyberCSV.py:12: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  hostData  = data[data['Platform ID'].str.startswith("CS-Unix-")][data['Safe'].str.startswith("CS-NOI-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT")] [['Platform ID', 'Safe', 'Target system address','Failure reason']]
```

Secondly,  Is there a way to use wildcard within dataframe like i have

`data['Safe'].str.startswith("CDS-NOI-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT")` where i want to use `data['Safe'].str.startswith("CDS-*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT")`

is this possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can chain [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) masks or use [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) - `^` is for match start of string, `.*` is for any string and `$` for end:

```
mask = data['Safe'].str.startswith("CDS") & data['Safe'].str.endswith("DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT")
```

Or regex:

```
mask = data['Safe'].str.contains("^CDS-.*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT$")
```

**Sample**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Safe':['CDS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT',
                             'CDS-NhjghOI-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT',
                             'CDS-NhjghOI-DEFAULT',
                             'ACDS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT']})

print (data)
                            Safe
0          CDS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
1  CDS-NhjghOI-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT
2            CDS-NhjghOI-DEFAULT
3         ACDS-DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT

mask = data['Safe'].str.contains("^CDS-.*DEFAULT-UNIX-ROOT$")
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: Safe, dtype: bool
```

Comment: let me try , nice solution.